# how to save previous hssf cell value inn android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hssf

```
            HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.createSheet();
            HSSFRow hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(0);
            HSSFCell hssfCell = hssfRow.createCell(i);
            hssfCell.setCellValue(name.getText().toString());
```

i want to store previous hssf cell value in excel , when i enter new cell value it does,nt store previous hssf cell value...

Comment: Give more conetext to your question.

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.